# Error: create: failed to create: the server responded with the status code 413 but did not return more information

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My helm was properly working and I have been working with it this morning for a couple of hours. Then, suddenly it stopped working and the only error I get is **Error: create: failed to create: the server responded with the status code 413 but did not return more information**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I, without paying much attention or caring about the location of the file, was saving some log data from a couple of Kubernetes pods in the same directory as my template files. Once I deleted the log file, which was apparently quite large, I got rid of the error and my helm install command was working. I guess HELM cares about the sizes of the files even if they have nothing to do with your helm installation. This was my case though, your case could be different. But I hope this post helps you in any way. It was a weird one in this case.

I guess the same thing could happen if your charts grew too much.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message when trying to install kube-prometheus-stack.

I have an nginx load balancer in front of kube-apiserver for high availability.
**Note:** don't confuse this with nginx ingress controler.

By default nginx has `client_max_body_size 1m`.
To solve the problem I had to increase this setting by editing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in my ubuntu VM:

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 10m;
}
```

And if you're using Rancher you need to edit the nginx-ingress-controller's configMap from the `local` cluster where Rancher is installed and add:

```yaml
data:
  proxy-body-size: 10m
```